# How to use "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL" Operators in JSON API Collections?

Tags: 8

I am creating an API with Conditions and Operators. For `'='` and `'<>'` operators its working fine. But for `"IS NULL"` and `"IS NOT NULL"` operators the response is 400: Bad Request.

```
{{URL}}/jsonapi/node/CONTENT_TYPE?filter[filter1][condition][path]=TAXONOMY_FIELD.drupal_internal__tid&filter[filter1][condition][value]={{TID}}&filter[filter1][condition][operator]=IS NULL
```

**Request:**
[image]

**Response:**
The error says: `Filters using the 'IS NULL' operator should not provide a value.`
[image]

Should the operators be encoded ? If yes, then which encoding should be used and what is the encoded string for these operators ?

Comment: Paameters are correct , I think the path which you have given is wrong.Also why you are not giving tid value directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line, because value is supposed to be null

```
&filter[filter1][condition][value]={{TID}}
```